# FOR function in R studio

Tags: r, for-loop

Can somebody please explain why this code results in 15?

```
k<-0
for(i in 1:3){
  k<-k+1
  for(j in 1:2){
    k<-k+2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because writing `for(i in 1:3)` means "do the following for each value between 1 and 3, and if you come across the letter i, replace it with that value". As it happens, neither i nor j appear in the body of the loops, but that doesn't stop the loops from executing

So the code expands to this:

```r
k <- 0
# first outer loop with i = 1
{
  k <- k + 1      # k = 1
  {
    # inner loop runs two times for j = 1 and j = 2
    k <- k + 2    # k = 3
    k <- k + 2    # k = 5
  }
}
# second outer loop with i = 2
{
  k <- k + 1      # k = 6
  {
    # inner loop runs two times for j = 1 and j = 2
    k <- k + 2    # k = 8
    k <- k + 2    # k = 10
  }
}
# third outer loop with i = 3
{
  k <- k + 1      # k = 11
  {
    # inner loop runs two times for j = 1 and j = 2
    k <- k + 2    # k = 13
    k <- k + 2    # k = 15
  }
}
```

so the sum of all the values added to k is 15. And you can see why we need `for` loops!

Comment: Nice answer, Allan. It unrolls the loops into iterative steps, clearly (I think) showing what is happening as it happens.

Answer (score 1):

So here is what it does;

1. `k <- k+1` results in k = 1
2. The inner loops takes place which loops 2 times each time adding 2 to k
   So first time k becomes 3 then 5

Those two steps keep repeating 3 times (due to the outer loop);

So for second run it will add 1 (5 + 1 = 6) then it will add 2 twice (k = 10)
And for third run it will add 1 (10 + 1 = 11) then it will add 2 twice (k = 15)

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop i.e.

```
  for(j in 1:2){
    k<-k+2
  }
```

adds 2 to k twice. So, each time the whole loop completes 4 is added to k.

Each iteration of the outer loop i.e.

```
  k<-k+1
  for(j in 1:2){
    k<-k+2
  }
```

adds 1+ 4=5 to k. there are 3 iterations, so outer loop adds 3*5=15 to k.

The initial value of k is 0. So, the final value of k will be 0+15=15.

Answer (score 0):

So you have three loops i, each of which runs two loops j:

```
in i = 1
 0 + 1 = 1; then j=1, you have 1+2=3 and j=2, you have 3+2=5 ==> k is now 5

in i = 2
  5 + 1 = 6; then j=1, you have 6+2=8 and j=2, you have 8+2=10 ==> k is now 10

in the 3rd loop, i = 3,
 10+1=11; then j=1 gives you 11+2 =13 and j=2 gives 13+2=15 ==> hence k is 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full progress

```
i = 1: k <- k + 1 gives 1
j = 1: k<-k+2 gives 3
j = 2: k<-k+2 gives 5

i = 2: k <- k + 1 gives 6
j = 1: k<-k+2 gives 8
j = 2: k<-k+2 gives 10

i = 3: k <- k + 1 gives 11
j = 1: k<-k+2 gives 13
j = 2: k<-k+2 gives 15
```

then finally you will get 15